# Why does postgres use index scan over sequential scan even with a mismatching data type on the indexed column and query condition

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    id integer primary key,
    full_name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    tier bigint
);
```

Filled random data into this table using following block:

```
do $$
declare
begin
    FOR counter IN 1 .. 100000 LOOP
        INSERT INTO staff (id, full_name, department, tier)
        VALUES (nextval('staff_sequence'), 
                random_string(10),
                random_string(20), 
                get_department(),
                floor(random() * 5 + 1)::bigint);
    end LOOP;
end; $$
```

After the data is populated, I created an index on this table on the `tier` column:

```
create index staff_tier_idx on staff(tier);
```

Although I created this index, when I execute a query using this column, I want this index **NOT** to be used. To accomplish this, I tried to execute this query:

```
select count(*) from staff where tier=1::numeric;
```

Due to mismatching data types on the indexed column and the query condition, I thought the index will not be used & instead a sequential scan will be executed. However, when I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the above query I get the following output:

```
Aggregate  (cost=2349.54..2349.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=17.078..17.079 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using staff_tier_idx on staff  (cost=0.29..2348.29 rows=500 width=0) (actual time=0.022..15.925 rows=19942 loops=1)
        Filter: ((tier)::numeric = '1'::numeric)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 80058
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.305 ms
Execution Time: 17.130 ms
```

Showing that the index has indeed been used.

How do I change this so that the query uses a sequential scan instead of the index? This is purely for a testing/learning purposes.

If its of any importance, I am running this on an Amazon RDS database instance

Comment: From here [Planner methof conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html): `SET enable_indexonlyscan TO off;`

Comment: It rather ruins the example when it uses functions we don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Filter" rows of the plan like

```
 Rows Removed by Filter: 80058
```

you can see that the index is not being used as a real index, but just as a skinny table, testing the casted condition for each row.  This appears favorable because the index is less than 1/4 the size of the table, while the default ratio of random_page_cost/seq_page_cost = 4.

In addition to just outright disabling index scans as Adrian already suggested, you could also discourage this "skinny table" usage by just increasing random_page_cost, since pages of indexes are assumed to be read in random order.

Another method would be to change the query so it can't use the index-only scan.  For example, just using `count(full_name)` would do that, as PostgreSQL then needs to visit the table to make sure full_name is not NULL (even though it has a constraint asserting that already--sometimes it is not very clever)

Which method is better depends on what it is you are wanting to test/learn.

Comment: Flat out disabling index scans was not an option as I want index scans to be enabled but Postgres to choose not to use the index. Adding `count(full_name)` did the trick. If it has to visit the table to make sure `full_name` is not null, with `count(*)` won't it have to visit the table to make sure `full_name` AND `department` is not null?

Comment: count(*) counts every row, even if all columns in the row are NULL.  It is a bit special.  As long as the table page is marked "all visible" in the VM, it won't need to visit that page.